# Rails 4 How to generate a SN based on the input of one field in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I generate a rails resource `Book` with `name, telephone, SN.` And I want the Rails to generate a SN combined with the `telephone` the user input and `the time`.

For example, the form shows name and telephone for the user to input.
 Then the user types the name:`A` and phone number:`123456`. after the user submits the form at`00:45 AM`. The rails add a record with`A , 123456, 1234560045`.

If I set the SN in, it is unable to generate based on telephone.

```
def new
    @book = Book.new 
  end
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "set the SN in"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model set the SN column before save. I hope this is what you were looking for

```
before_save :set_sn

  def set_sn
    self.sn  = "#{telephone}#{Time.now.strftime('%I%M')}"
  end
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, I forgot to format my time in my answer lol

Answer (score 0):

In your model, add to `book.rb`:

```
before_create :add_serial # add this before your methods
```

Then add this as a private method at the bottom of your models:

```
private
def add_serial
  new_sn = self.telephone+Time.now
  self.SN = new_sn
end
```